# View delays before refreshing

Tags: android, view

I am working on a connect 5 game. I have the board as a custom view. When a player playing against the engine makes a move the board does show the move until the engine makes its move. The engine moves relatively quickly so it. is not a big deal, but it is nonetheless noticeable.

I call invalidate() after the player's move is made, then I call the method to make the engine move on a different thread(AsyncTask). I was under the impression that after invalidate() is called the view refreshes itself, then the method to make the engine move would be called.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You're introducing race condition, `invalidate()` is propagated "upwards" in view hierarchy to notify your layout wants to redraw during next draw cycle. It is not guaranteed to trigger redraw instantly.

Whether you start your engine before or after `invalidate()` call doesn't matter, in either case it cannot be determined if it finishes before or after draw cycle.

If you want to have your layout refreshed the moment your `AsyncTask` finishes you should call `invalidate()` during result callback.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you know where I can learn more about the process? And also I want the user to see the move played before the engines makes its move. As I have it now the player is waiting for the engine's move for a fraction a second without seeing his move.

Comment: @VladimirLouis just call invalidate in both cases if you want to redraw layout twice.

Comment: that is what I am doing. The same method that plays the move for the player also plays the move for the engine.